# Multiple (simultaneous) users in R Shiny with access to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, r, shiny

I have a Shiny application (hosted on shinyapps.io) that records a user's click of certain actionButtons to a MySQL database. I'd love some advice on a few things:

- where to put the `dbConnect` code (i.e. inside or outside the `shinyServer` function)
- when to close the connection (as I was running into the problem of too many open connections)

Each addition to the database just adds a new row, so users aren't accessing and modifying the same elements. The reason I ask this is I was running into problem of multiple users not being able to use the app at the same time (with the error "Disconnected from server") and I wasn't sure if it was from the MySQL connections.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you hosting your app on shinyapps.io or your own Shiny Server (open source edition or professional edition)?

Comment: I host several apps for use in my laboratory.  In order to prevent too many open connections, I open a new connection every time an action is initiated and close it as soon as I can.  In other words, for each action button, the event observer will open a new database connection, run the necessary query, then close the connection.  It may help to develop a function that you can use as a short cut to making your connection.

Comment: From my experience, it's better to open and then close a new connection for each querry (just like you did). I've tried openning a single connection and closing it with `session$onSessionEnded`. The problem with that was that the database we were using had a limit of connections that could be done at the same time.

Comment: How many users? And how often will events occur? There will be overhead in opening and closing connections

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html

Comment: @warmoverflow I'm hosting it on shiny apps.io.

Comment: @James likely no more than 15 at a time and a click will likely occur ever 5 seconds.

Comment: @Benjamin I'll try what you suggested!

Comment: @Carl this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Someone in the comments posted about the `pool` package, which serves this exact purpose! Here's the relevant parts of my `server.R` code:

```
library(shiny)
library(RMySQL)
library(pool)

pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  user='username', 
  password='password', 
  dbname='words', 
  host='blahblahblah')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  ## function to write to databse
  writeToDB <- function(word, vote){
    query <- paste("INSERT INTO word_votes (vote, word) VALUES (", vote, ", '", word, "');", sep="")
    conn <- poolCheckout(pool) 
    dbSendQuery(conn, query) 
    conn <- poolReturn(conn)

  ## rest of code
  }
```

I added the `poolCheckout` and `poolReturn` to run successfully and prevent leaks.